# Determine which commit the repo is currently merging (MERGE_HEAD)

Tags: git, git-merge

Lets assume I have really bad memory retention and have a repo that is in the middle of a merge conflict that has not been resolved yet.

A `git status` will show you the fact that you have `unmerged paths`, but it does not show the `MERGE_HEAD` commit/sha of this merge conflict.

Is there a built-in `git` cmd option that will show this without having to manually test if `.git` is a file or directory and follow the submodule dirs to `cat` the `MERGE_HEAD` file to `git log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there are three places this information can be had.

First, the conflict markers will tell you.

```
diff --cc one
index 1f7391f,a7453f0..0000000
--- a/one
+++ b/one
@@@ -1,1 -1,1 +1,5 @@@
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +master
++=======
+ feature
++>>>>>>> feature
```

That tells me I'm merging `feature` into `HEAD`.  `git status` will tell me what branch `HEAD` is.

If you `cat .git/MERGE_MSG` it will tell you what branch you're merging.

```
$ cat .git/MERGE_MSG 
Merge branch 'feature'

# Conflicts:
#   one
```

Finally, `cat .git/MERGE_HEAD` will tell you what SHA you're merging with.  This can be turned into a branch name with `git branch --contains`.

```
cat .git/MERGE_HEAD | xargs git branch --contains
```

Comment: Thanks, this is done via an automated fork/branch stalker and I was hoping for some built-in git option that did not require cat'ing a file (some of mine are submodules so `.git` can be a file, thus a submodule directory pointer, not an 'issue'  but again looking for that magic git porcelain)

Comment: @SushiHangover Magic Git porcelain is going to be digging around in the `.git` directory, so catting some `.git` file isn't much different. I hear you that it would be very nice if this were a command.